# Kafka Streams Application Reset Tool didn't work, and could not reset topic offset to 0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I referenced https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/ and tried to use [Kafka Streams Application Reset Tool](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html) for resetting the kafka streams application. But even I did all prerequisite and the necessary steps, when I check the resetting topic offset by `/opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh`, the CURRENT-OFFSET is still not 0.

Anyone could help with that? Will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version you are using, the reset tool commit zero of "beginning offset" --if you topic was subject to retention and was truncated, "beginning offset" is not zero any longer.

This is by design and actually better than committing zero because zero would be an invalid offset for this case, and on application restart `auto.offset.reset` would trigger (and if it's not configured as "earliest" you would get some undesired behavior).

You be able to get the current earliest offset from a topic via `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell`.

Comment: if the Kafka Streams application's input topic is subject to retention, then what would be a best way to reset Kafka Streams application so that it can reprocess the topic from offset 0? If the reset tool didn't work, how do we do it manually? Thanks! @Matthias J. Sax

Comment: It a topic was subject to retention, there is not data at offset zero -- the data got deleted. Why do you want to commit offset zero?